# use two Directory and Alias

Tags: apache2

Is it legal to use two Directory and Alias in httpd.conf apache as in the following?

```
<Directory "C:/Projects/DCS/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /dcs/ C:/Projects/DCS/


<Directory "C:/Projects/DCS_NEW/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /dcs_new/ C:/Projects/DCS_NEW/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not? As long as you're not assigning more than one Alias with the same URL-path, it's fine. By "same URL-path" I mean the first parameter, e.g.:

```
Alias /foo C:/some/path
Alias /foo C:/some/other/path
```

Comment: I am going to use the URL as localhost/dcs   and localhost/dcs_new respectively.Is this OK ?

Comment: I could get the dcs working but not the dcs_new.have I missed out any steps?  I did restart the Apache.

Comment: @redcoder If `C:/Projects/DCS_NEW/` is a valid directory that apache has read permissions in, then the problem is something else. Check your error logs.

Comment: you mean apache error log? here is the error log : [Fri Sep 21 11:19:52 2012] [error] [client 192.168.3.92] File does not exist: C:/Tools/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/dcs_new

Comment: error log  says : [Fri Sep 21 11:19:52 2012] [error] [client 192.168.3.92] File does not exist: C:/Tools/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/dcs_new.    My dcs and dcs_new are under C:Projects folder... Do I need to do any other setting ?

Comment: @redcoder That's because you're alias URL-path is `/dcs_new/` and you are requesting `/dcs_new`. No trailing slash, they're not the same thing. Either request with the trailing slash or remove it from your alias.